# Image processing - turn spotty white shapes solid

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, convolution, scikit-image

I have a binary black and white image like in this screenshot:

[image]

I want those spotty white regions to turn into solid white blobs. What type of operation (ideally in skimage or numpy) would I use for this?

Comment: Morphological dilation probably...

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Feel free to convert this to answer.

Comment: It’s ok - it was just a little hint. Maybe add the code you came up with as an answer for other folks to learn from, and accept your own answer and grab the points - all perfectly within the SO rules.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea on stuff like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887222/image-processing-eliminate-arc-like-smears