# Watershed segmentation on spherical reflecting objects

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am trying to do some image segmentation with watershed to detect all balls in an image. I have followed a pyimage tuto. But I am getting very poor results. My guess is that the reflexion is the problem. Still the image is pretty clean and the instances look quite separable.

Am I using the correct approach here? Did I miss somethings?
I tested cellpose and I get almost perfect results. It's not the same approach of course and I was hopping to get something with "classical" computer-vision techniques.

Following is the code I have, the original image and the current result. I have tried to change the parameters, but I am not sure about what I am doing here. I also looked at `inRange`, but I am afraid the balls are never of the same color.

original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7595R.jpg

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import cv2
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.segmentation import watershed
import imutils
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('balls.jpg')
gray = - cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

plt.imshow(gray)

# Things I tried...
# gray = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
# hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# compute the exact Euclidean distance from every binary
# pixel to the nearest zero pixel, then find peaks in this
# distance map
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=30, labels=thresh)
# perform a connected component analysis on the local peaks,
# using 8-connectivity, then appy the Watershed algorithm
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=thresh)

# draw on mask
for label in np.unique(labels):
    # if the label is zero -> 'background'
    if label == 0:
        continue

    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255
    # detect contours in the mask and grab the largest one
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # draw a circle enclosing the object
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "#{}".format(label), (int(x) - 10, int(y)), 
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)

plt.imshow(img)
```

The labels : https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6hZb.png

[image: Result]

Comment: You may want to display individual labels instead of enclosing circles to get more insights on how well watershed segmentation works for your image. You can also try to invert image colors or to tweak the threshold.

Comment: @fdermishin I just tried to display the labels, and it's really bad. I will update the question. I played with the threshold and could not improve anything. Same for working with HSV. But I might have done all that wrong. FYI, I tested cellpose (I added a note in the question too) and it works. But I would prefer not to use DL.

Comment: Yes, this is very much the wrong approach. Take a look at `thresh`, it is not the type of image where the watershed of distance transform is useful.

Comment: If you have influence over the image acquisition, you can do many things to make this easier: change the illumination to be more diffuse, use a background color that is distinct from the colors of the balls and the illumination, use transmitted light imaging, etc, etc.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the spheres have bright spot inside of them, so you can't find out if a region in the image is background or foreground. After doing distance transform it becomes impossible to distinguish one sphere from another. It may be helpful to threat them as hollow circles, see this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888661/image-processing-fill-in-hollow-circles

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't have an influence over the image acquisition. And I would like a robust approach. I thought Watersheding would be a good approach as it looked very much similar to the example with the coins in opencv's doc.

Comment: @fdermishin Thanks for the link. I did try a bit to "close" the spot but did not manage. I will try with the code in the link.

Comment: given *that* picture, I'd just pick one ball as a template and run matchTemplate. they all look the same, reflection-wise. that does require you to pick a ball as a template though. if I had to do this as an industrial optical inspection task, I would definitely *fix* scene, lighting, acquisition

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Interesting approach. Would you have some code example?

Comment: @fdermishin I tested the approach and it seems to work. If you would make a clean answer here (the code on the other side seems overly complicated), I would gladly accept it :)

Comment: another idea: circular Hough transform or (fast) radial symmetry transform (FRST). those would maybe find the outlines of the balls and respond.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hough transform is working good as suggested by fdermishin in the posted link. I did not check FRST.

Comment: great. no comment actually used the word "Hough" so I thought it wasn't mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

matchTemplate "solution" with [`opencv/samples/mouse_and_match.py`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/mouse_and_match.py)

use whatever you like to find the peaks.

yes, with this approach you gotta pick a template manually.

to fix that, there could be approaches exploiting self-similarity (auto-correlation). exercise to the reader.

you can't pick whole balls because their sizes vary, so that's a huge downside to template matching already, but also a rectangle around a circle contains a significant amount of non-object pixels, which drives down the correlation score wherever that part varies.

picking the reflection works (off of a medium ball) because the reflection shows an environment with nice strong contrast.

notice the one small ball near the top, slightly to the right? that's not doing so well for a bunch of reasons.

[image]

Comment: That ball does match well - it has a bright spot on the right hand image. You may be misreading the location

Comment: Also you locations will not be centroids, unless you centered your reference image relative to the balls. Perhaps you did. Nevertheless, I like what you have done.

Comment: As I understand it, I could just use a circular patch on any shape and scale differently the image (I have a very limited set of size).  Something like this https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/

Comment: of course you have to adjust the coordinates. they're relative to the top left of the template, so they're the origins of rectangles matching the template. the center of the rectangle needn't be the centroid of what you picked. that's a minor detail. and that weak ball on the top off to the right, I didn't say it's not there in the response map, but that it's weak.

Comment: @Y0da yes correct, you can multiscale this to catch varying sizes. just adds some more processing time. given that this already ran in no noticeable time, I'd say that's a good idea.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz As it's a python question, I would accept your answer if you would post some minimal code to solve the task.

Comment: the code is a sample in OpenCV. I could link to it on their github but I won't slash that down to "minimal". peak/blob finding: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html. my answer is a sketch, a proof of concept.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I disagree here as the path you are linking to could change. That's why we always ask people to not post link answers. Also, from the image on the right, I don't get that it detected all the spheres. The doc is more explicit on this regards as it outlines the elements. Same goes from the pyimage code I linked. It is true that you provide a concept but so does the others in the comments before you.